# Is " VOA Learning English" a proper noun？

Tags: nouns

> From ***VOA Learning English***, welcome to The Making of a Nation,
>   our weekly program about American history for people learning English.
>   I’m Steve Ember.

Is "*VOA Learning English*" a proper noun? Is "*Learning English*" a compound noun? How to parse "*VOA + a compound noun*" ?

Is it possible to be understood "From VOA Learning English" as : Learning English from VOA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*VOA* is a short form of the proper name *Voice of America*, which is an official agency of the US government for public communications outside the US.

*Learning English* is also a proper name, that of a department or branch of VOA which offers English-language instruction and supplementary materials through radio, television, internet and mobile-phone broadcasts.

So *VOA Learning English* is the full name—a “compound” proper name if you like—of the producing organization, just like (for instance) the *US Department of Agriculture*. *The Making of a Nation* is a series of broadcasts on US history produced and broadcast by *VOA Learning English*.

The *From* at the beginning of the sentence is a conventional broadcast opening which tells the listener or viewer where the broadcast originates; it is structured to say as well that the *welcome* comes from the producing organization.

> From us, welcome to the program.